# Testing Foursquare "Apps Platform"

Tags: foursquare

I have registered my app with Foursquare, including registering for "User Push Api"

I have tested the checkin push using their website link "Send a test push" with successful results.

I have worked through Oauth process, and successfully get a token and can make calls with that.

Now I would alike to test the "User Push API" with the actual foursquare app. My understanding is that in order for my app to receive the pushed checkin notifications, my app has to be "Connected" with my Foursquare account.

What do I do to make this connection? I don't see my app listed in the gallery of apps to connect. Are there calls I need to make once I have the token to finalize the connection process? I understand that while this API is under development, that my app cannot appear in the main gallery. It seems that I should be able to connect my app somewhere since I am registered as developer.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth for more details on how to connect with your app.

Additionally, even if your app does not appear in the app gallery, a draft version of your app details appears at https://foursquare.com/app/CLIENT_ID which you can review and will have a connect button automatically generated for you.